# Iteration stops after the first matching instance when I want it to carry on

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

So the idea here is that I'm comparing two ArrayLists. If the word from PirateDictionary matches the phrase from Phrase then you print Phrase +1, if it doesn't match you simply return the original word. Now my code does the comparing just fine, but when it gets to the first matching case it prints off Phrase +1 as intended but then it stops when there are still words to compare, and this is where I don't know what I'm missing. Here is the method that I'm using:

```
 public void compareLists(){
        String nameSearch;

        for(PirateDictionary w: words){
            nameSearch = w.toString();
            Iterator<Phrase> it = phrases.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                Phrase c = it.next();
                if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
                    System.out.println( it.next().toString());      
                    return;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(w.toString());
        }
    }
```

IF anyone could have a look at this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Read your code again, after the first ``System.out``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said your code works fine until the first matching case is reached. In your code this is the point at which the condition in the `if`-clause is evaluated to `true`:

```
if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
  System.out.println( it.next().toString());      
 return;
}
```

If a match is found, the matched string is printed to `System.out` and then you return (leave the method)- hence no other comparison will take place. Please remove the `return` statement to continue checking the rest of the words.

Comment: Hmm  thanss, that kind of helps because it carries on going, but now it prints off both the original word and the translation

Comment: Check your second `System.out.println`. It assures as part of the for-loop that each of the words in the PirateDictionary is printed. If also a match is found, then this match is printed, too -> makes two outputs to the console.